# Get Element and append multiple times Javascript

Tags: javascript, append

I need to get an element and append it multiple times inside its parent.

HTML

```
<main>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/arch?t=1493746896324/" />
        <div class="cover"></div>
      </div>
</main>
```

JS

```
const main = document.querySelector("main");
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");

for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
  main.innerHTML += wrapper;
}
```

RESULT

`[object HTMLDivElement]` is inserted instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Cloning a Node

- [ParentNode.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append)
- [Node.cloneNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)

```js
const main = document.querySelector("main");
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");

for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
  main.append(wrapper.cloneNode(true));
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/arch?t=1493746896324/" />
    <div class="cover"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

### Concatenate using outerHTML

Otherwise, given `innerHTML` and manipulating **Strings** you could do:

- [Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)
- [Element.outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)

```js
const main = document.querySelector("main");
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");

for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
  main.innerHTML += wrapper.outerHTML;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/arch?t=1493746896324/" />
    <div class="cover"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

### Pros Cons

Both the above results will end up in the same markup

```html
<main>
  <div class="wrapper">...</div>
  ......
  <div class="wrapper">...</div>
</main>
```

with the only difference that by using cloning with `true`, every originally assigned listeners or *data* will be **cloned** as well;
whilst using concatenation `+=` with `.outerHTML()` is basically a simple HTML markup concatenation with not much other benefits.